# Remove lists falling after selected list

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp

I am stuck on a problem where I want to remove all the list that fall after selected list.
I have created [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8TZzD/1/) here but it doesn't work. For example, if I select item from first drop-down then next two should removed, or if I select from second drop-down then third should be removed.

#### HTML

```
<div id='levels'>
<select id="level" class="parent" name="data[level][]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="level" class="parent" name="data[level][]">
    <option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
 <select id="level" class="parent" name="data[level][]">
    <option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
    </select>   
    </div>
```

#### Javascript

```
$("#levels").on('change', function() {
    $(this).nextAll().remove();

    });​
```

I want to achieve this without assigning different class names or div names to each list.

**Cakephp Code**

**Master File**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


 $("select").on('change', function() {
    $(this).nextAll('select').remove();
        $("<div>").load('/dashboard/details/show_levels',function() {
    $("#levels").append($(this).html());

});
})


<div id=levels>

    <?php echo $form->input('level',array('options'=>$level,'type'=>'select','scroabble'=>true,'multiple'=>true, 'class'=>'parent')); ?>
</div>


});
```

**show_levels**

```
<?php
$abc=array('a','b','c','d');
echo $form->input('level',array('options'=>$abc,'type'=>'select','scroabble'=>true,'multiple'=>true, 'class'=>'parent')); ?>
```

---

***Update:***

**Follwing solution worked for me**

Replaced

```
 $(this).nextAll('select').remove();
```

with

```
$(this).parents().nextUntil().remove();
```

Not sure how it worked, and whats the difference between two.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't only work the first time? The fact that you are using `on` in the way you are, it won't be re-bound to the new elements appended to `#levels`. If you use `on` the way I did, it might fix it. This is because the `onchange` event is bound to each `<select>` element on page load. When you change the value of one, the following elements are removed (and their `onchange` event is unbound). When you put new elements back into the page, they shouldn't have the `onchange` event bound to them again.

Comment: And binding the `onchange` event to `#levels` does nothing - a `<div>` doesn't have an `onchange` event. If you use `on` like I proposed, it would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follwing solution worked for me**

Replaced

```
 $(this).nextAll('select').remove();
```

with

```
$(this).parents().nextUntil().remove();
```

Not sure how it worked, and whats the difference between two.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$("select").on('change', function() {
$(this).nextAll('select').remove();
});​
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/8LYz8/)

Comment: @Deadlock did you get any error? please check console, it is working fine please check fiddle

Comment: That works absolutely fine in the fiddle, but I am trying the same in cakephp and it doesn't work, I am loading the next list by load function and appending them to first list...
But plain html generated is same as I posted in fiddle

Comment: if plain html is same as in fiddle it should work, what error you get there?

Comment: New List is being appended every-time but previous generated list are not removed

Comment: Updated post with answer, not sure how it worked
BTW voted up for your efforts, really appreciate it..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you want to `remove` them, as you said "hide", but to use `change` for your scenario, you can use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#levels").on("change", ".parent", function () {
        $(this).nextAll().hide();
    });
});
```

By the way, your `<select>` elements need to have unique `id` attributes, not all have "level".

Something that makes more sense to me, is something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HRh2d/

Comment: That is working absolutely fine in fiddle, not in cakephp..
I have updated my cakephp code, please have a look

Comment: Updated post with answer, not sure how it worked
BTW voted up for your efforts, really appreciate it..

Comment: +1 for `$("#levels").on("change", ".parent", function () {
 ...
    });`

Answer (score -1):

Try .siblings() instead of nextAll

Also your selects should have unique IDs

Comment: OP is trying to get rid of the child divs, not all the divs that are related directly.